# jquery load function

Tags: jquery

i have this jQuery function:

```
$("#text").load("test3.php?id="+ Math.random());
```

And this code is in page:
user.php

When i runt this page in this address:
http://127.0.0.1/user.php - everthing is OK.

But, When i runt this page in this address:
http://127.0.0.1/user/

in div "text" insert all root page.

test3.php page code:

```
<?php
echo "test 678";
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in div 'text' insert all root page"? I'm afraid I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not **quite** following the question, but there's a difference there and so this may help:

When the browser resolves a relative URL, it uses the document location. Your two document locations are different in that one of them looks like a path to which `test3.php` should be *appended*, the other looks like a page name that `test3.php` should *replace*:

```
http://127.0.0.1/user.php + test3.php = http://127.0.0.1/test3.php
```

but

```
http://127.0.0.1/user/ + test3.php = http://127.0.0.1/user/test3.php
                                                      ^-- note the difference
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is when you call `http://127.0.0.1/user/`, you're like calling `http://127.0.0.1/user/index.php`. You should have a folder named `user` which inside it has the file `index.php` to make it work.

I suggest you rename `user.php` to `index.php` and move it to folder `user`.